# Erro na hora de adicionar FK

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Encontrei apenas sobre esse tipo de erro em "Select", segui todas as restrições, mas não funcionou!

Erro a partir da linha : 86 no comando -

```
alter table tb_consulta add constraint fk_tb_consulta_tb_tratamento foreign key (idtrat) references tb_paciente(cod_tratamento)
```

Relatório de erros -

```
ORA-00904: "IDTRAT": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Erro a partir da linha : 90 no comando -

```
alter table tb_pagamento add constraint fk_tb_pagamento_tb_tratamento foreign key (cod_tratamento_tratamento) references tb_tratamento(cod_tratamento)
```

Relatório de erros -

```
ORA-00904: "COD_TRATAMENTO_TRATAMENTO": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Código completo:

```
create table tb_paciente (
nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cpf varchar(11) NOT NULL,
cidade varchar(45 ) NOT NULL,
bairro varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cep varchar(11) NOT NULL
);

create table tb_telefone(
cod_paciente varchar(11),
telefone varchar(11)
);

create table tb_tratamento(
cod_tratamento int NOT NULL,
tipo_tratamento varchar (45) not null,
valor float not null
);

create table tb_consulta(
id_paciente int not null,
cod_consulta varchar(45) not null,
horario_inicio TIMESTAMP not null,
horario_final TIMESTAMP  not null,
cod_equipe int not null,
tb_equipe_cod_equipe int not null,
tb_tratamento_cod_tratamento int not null
);

create table tb_consulta_material(
cod_consulta int not null,
tb_material_cod_material varchar(45) not null,
tb_consulta_cod_material varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_material(
nome varchar(45) not null,
cod_material varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_equipe(
cod_equipe int not null,
nome varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_funcionario(
nome varchar(45) not null,
cod_equipe int not null,
cpf varchar(45) not null,
tipo varchar(45) not null,
tb_equipe_cod_equipe int not null
);

create table tb_salas(
numero int not null,
cod_consutorio int not null,
tb_consultorio_cnpj int not null,
tb_equipe_cod_equipe int not null
);

create table tb_consultorio(
nome varchar(45) not null,
cnpj int not null
);

create table tb_pagamento(
cod_pagamento int not null,
valor int not null

);
alter table tb_pagamento add constraint PK_TB_PAGAMENTO primary key(cod_pagamento);
alter table TB_CONSULTA add constraint PK_TB_CONSULTA primary key(cod_consulta);
alter table TB_consultorio add constraint PK_TB_consultorio primary key(cnpj);
alter table TB_equipe add constraint PK_TB_equipe primary key(cod_equipe);
alter table TB_funcionario add constraint PK_TB_funcionario primary key(cpf);
alter table TB_material add constraint PK_TB_material primary key(cod_material);
alter table TB_paciente add constraint PK_TB_paciente primary key(cpf);
alter table TB_salas add constraint PK_TB_salas primary key(numero);
alter table tb_telefone add cpf_paciente varchar (11) not null;
alter table TB_telefone add constraint PK_TB_telefone primary key(cpf_paciente);
alter table TB_tratamento add constraint PK_TB_tratamento primary key(cod_tratamento);
alter table tb_tratamento add cpf_paciente varchar (11) not null;
alter table tb_salas drop column cod_consutorio;
--paciente para tratamento
alter table tb_tratamento add constraint fk_tb_tratamento_tb_paciente foreign key (cpf_paciente) references tb_paciente(cpf); 
alter table tb_consulta add constraint fk_tb_consulta_tb_tratamento foreign key (idtrat) references tb_paciente(cod_tratamento); 
-- paciente para telefone
alter table tb_telefone add constraint fk_tb_telefone_tb_paciente foreign key (cpf_paciente) references tb_paciente(cpf);
--tratamento para pagamento
alter table tb_pagamento add constraint fk_tb_pagamento_tb_tratamento foreign key (cod_tratamento_tratamento) references tb_tratamento(cod_tratamento);
```

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns erros nos 2 comandos:

No comando da linha 86:

```
alter table tb_consulta add constraint fk_tb_consulta_tb_tratamento foreign key (idtrat) references tb_paciente(cod_tratamento);
```

Nesse comando, pelo que entendi, você quer criar uma chave estrangeira entre a tb_consulta e a tb_tratamento certo? Mas você fez um references para a tb_paciente.

Então o comando deve ser:

```
alter table tb_consulta add constraint fk_tb_consulta_tb_tratamento foreign key (cod_tratamento) references tb_tratamento(cod_tratamento);
```

No comando da linha 90, você está tentando criar uma chave estrangeira entre a tb_pagamento e a tb_tratamento, então você deve informar uma coluna de ambas as tabelas, e no caso, você informou uma coluna inexistente, "COD_TRATAMENTO_TRATAMENTO"

Na criação das tabelas, você não precisa dar o nome para as colunas igual ao nome das tabelas, isso não é um padrão, e certamente você terá inúmeros problemas no futuro se o fizer.

Eu prefiro criar as primary key e foreign key na criação da tabela.

Uma outra coisa que você pode fazer para facilitar bastante é utilizar o auto_increment para as primary keys.

uma recomendação seria assim, modifique a seu critério:

```
create table tb_paciente (
cod_paciente int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cpf varchar(11) NOT NULL,
cidade varchar(45 ) NOT NULL,
bairro varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cep varchar(11) NOT NULL
);

create table tb_telefone(
cod_telefone int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
cod_paciente int, 
FOREIGN KEY (cod_paciente) REFERENCES tb_paciente(cod_paciente),
telefone varchar(11)
);

create table tb_tratamento(
cod_tratamento int NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
tipo_tratamento varchar (45) not null,
valor float not null,
cod_paciente int, 
FOREIGN KEY (cod_paciente) REFERENCES tb_paciente(cod_paciente)
);

create table tb_consulta(
cod_consulta int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_paciente int not null,
horario_inicio TIMESTAMP not null,
horario_final TIMESTAMP  not null,
cod_equipe int not null,
cod_tratamento int not null, 
FOREIGN KEY (cod_tratamento) REFERENCES tb_tratamento(cod_tratamento)
);

create table tb_consulta_material(
cod_consulta int not null,
cod_material varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_material(
cod_material int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_equipe(
cod_equipe int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_funcionario(
cod_funcionario int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(45) not null,
cod_equipe int not null,
cpf varchar(45) not null,
tipo varchar(45) not null
);

create table tb_salas(
numero int not null,
cod_consutorio int not null,
cod_equipe int not null
);

create table tb_consultorio(
cod_consultorio int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(45) not null,
cnpj int not null
);

create table tb_pagamento(
cod_pagamento int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
valor int not null,
cod_tratamento int,
FOREIGN KEY (cod_tratamento) REFERENCES tb_tratamento(cod_tratamento)
);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: se lhe foi muito útil, por favor, marque a questão como respondida, mas caso tenha mais alguma dúvida não hesite em perguntar.